How do I ignore exceptions when running integration tests using flutter drive?
I am trying to write integration tests for my application. I am using flutter drive to automate the user flow for flutter web view (canvas-kit render). On certain occasions (known), an exception is thrown by the application which causes flutter to consider the test as failed, even though they have been executed perfectly in the UI and they pass, but in the command line, it says.
==| EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK |==
Multiple Exceptions(2) were detected during the running of the current tests, and at least one was unexpected
...End of Failure 1

This is what my integration test looks like:
void main() {
    final binding = IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() as IntegrationTestWidgetsFlutterBinding;

    testWidgets('do something...', (tester) async {
      app.main();
.....
      });
    });

I tried to wrap it around a try and catch block, but the control flow exits the test once an exception is raised. How can I chose to ignore these exceptions ?
